# What does apt install --fix-policy actually do?

Tags: apt

I haven't found this information in man or other documents.
As I suggest, it restores all the basic packages, but does it?

```
$ apt install --fix-policy 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 krb5-locales
  libpam-cap light-locker-settings python-psutil ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk update-manager update-motd
  update-notifier
Suggested packages:
  python-psutil-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 krb5-locales
  libpam-cap light-locker-settings python-psutil ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk update-manager update-motd
  update-notifier
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Can you use it in an example command that apt will accept?

Comment: @user535733 updated post

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text; just copy-paste.

Comment: @fkraiem fixed this

Comment: Seems a bug to me. There is no `--fix-policy`. Suggestion: try with `--fix-nnnnn` just for the heck of it and see if it does the same. If so: 100% a bug. If that throws an error the bug is with the documentation.

Comment: @Rinzwind E: Command line option --fix-nnnnn is not understood in combination with the other options

Comment: @Rinzwind moreover, it works on both 16.04 and 18.04 versions, and maybe on previous versions

Comment: One thing I'd alert people to is that the `sudo apt install --fix-policy  --install-recommends` .. will reinstall packaged that have been removed. For example in maintain `libraoffice` via `flatpak`.  The `--fix-policy` option wanted to reinstall `libreoffice` and dependencies.  For me, I'm using the output as advise, and not allowing _fix policy_ to install something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm, according to this [(*old*) bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=578020;msg=2), and related [mailing list post](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2007/08/msg00000.html), `--fix-policy` is actually a neat option to make `apt` reconsider the "Recommends" dependencies of installed packages. So, originally if you had installed a package without its recommended packages, you can get it to install these extra packages by using `--fix-polcy`:

> If you want to see what would change if you had a system with
>   --install-recommends please run:
>
> ```
> # apt-get install --fix-policy --install-recommends
> ```
>
> If you want to know what package causes the installation of what
>   recommends please run:
>
> ```
> # apt-get install --fix-policy --install-recommends -o Debug::pkgDepCache::AutoInstall=true
> ```

The option has been around for some 11 years now, and the bug report asking for it to be included in the manpage for 8 years now.

So, I get, for example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --fix-policy -o Debug::pkgDepCache::AutoInstall=true
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
  Installing iio-sensor-proxy as Recommends of gnome-settings-daemon
  Installing indicator-printers as Recommends of unity
  Installing cinnamon-l10n as Recommends of nemo
  Installing nemo-fileroller as Recommends of nemo
  Installing python-bs4 as Recommends of python-lxml
```

Comment: I'm running 22.10 -- There is no `--fix-policy` entry in `apt`, `apt-get` ... Kind of weird, is it deprecated or something?